# Given boundary conditions and initial condition, solve the PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, heat-equation, wave-equation

> Question, solve the given PDE :
>
> $$ \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = a \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial x^2} -kC $$
> where a, k are constants.
>
> boundary conditions : $C= C_0$ at $x=0$, $C=0 $ at $x =$ infinitum
>
> initial condition : $C=0$ at $t=0$

My attempt :

> $$C(x,t) = X(x)~T(t)$$
> $$ C = X~T$$
> $$ \tag{1}\boxed{ \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = T^{\prime} X,~ \space \frac{\partial C}{\partial x}= X^{\prime}T, ~ \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial x^2} = X^{\prime \prime } T}$$
> replacing the partial derivatives into the Original equation :
> $$  T^{\prime}X = a ~X^{\prime \prime}T-k(X~T)    $$
> $$ X (T^{\prime} +KT)=a ~X^{\prime \prime}T  $$
> $$\frac{T^{\prime}}{T} = a ~\frac{ X^{\prime \prime}}{X} -k$$
> $$ \tag{2}\boxed{\frac{T^{\prime}}{T} = J,  ~\frac{ X^{\prime \prime}}{X} -k = J}$$
> equating each side to a constant $J = -\lambda^2$
> $$ \tag{3}\boxed{\frac{d T}{d t} = -\lambda^2 T ,~ \frac{d^2 X}{d x^2} = \left (\frac{-\lambda^2 + k}{a} \right) X}$$
> solving each differential equation :
> $$T(t) = Ae^{- \lambda t} , ~ ~~~X(x) = B ~e^{\left (x \sqrt{\frac{ k - \lambda^2}{a}} \right)} + C ~e^{\left (-x \sqrt{\frac{ k - \lambda^2}{a}} \right) } $$
> **Note :  D = AB and E = AC**
>
> **Corrected equation :**
> $$\tag{4} \boxed{{C(x,t) = \left(D \ e^ {x \sqrt{\frac{k-\lambda^2}{a}}} + E e^ {-x \sqrt{\frac{k-\lambda^2}{a}}} \right) e^{-\lambda t}}}$$
>
> confused with Boundary conditions and initial condition, could you guys help please

Comment: Have you plugged in your solution into the equation and conditions to check it? I guess not, because as it is now you have: 1) $C(0,t)=0 \ne C_0$ 2) $C(\infty,t) \sim \sin{x} \ne 0$

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires hey appreciate the response. I did plug in the condition values after evaluating $C(x,t)$. I will do it again

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires how is $C(\infty,t)$~$\sin x$? And I think first I should follow the boundary conditions and then initial. I might be wrong on that, do correct me

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires also $C = C_0$ at $x=0$ That’s a boundary condition

Comment: Hi. You asked to check your solution, I pointed that your solution does not fit your problem in, at least, two cases: your solution does not obey the boundary conditions. Neither at $x=0$ nor $x\rightarrow\infty$ Your method looks fine but something is  wrong. I would redo it, knowing that I was losing the boundary conditions on the way.

Comment: The only dependency on $x$ is a sine function. So as $x$ gets large $C(x,t)$ will *not* converge to 0. A correct answer will most likely have a $e^{-\alpha x}$  somewhere.

Comment: Also, there might be some error in you boundary and initial conditions, or I am missing something. You have $C(0,t)=C_0$ and $C(x,0)=0$ which implies that $C(0,0)=C_0$ and also $C(0,0)=0$, which is impossible (except for a zero solution, with $C_0=0$, but that is quite uninteresting)

Comment: If by "DNE" you mean "Does Not Exist", then you are wrong. It exists a (family of) solutions at infinity. What happens if $\lambda^2-k<0$, and thus the argument to the square root is negative?

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires I tried again, it seems the new corrected equation is correct, now I will apply the conditions

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires I see you mentioned $e^{ -\alpha x}$

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires conditions are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Laplace transform

$$
sC(s,x) - a C_{xx}(s,x)+ k C(s,x) = c(0,x)
$$

here $c(0,x) = 0$ so we follow with

$$
(s+k)C(s,x) - a C_{xx}(s,x)=0
$$

now solving for $x$ we have

$$
C(s,x) = \phi_1(s) e^{\sqrt{\frac{s+k}{a}}x}+\phi_2(s) e^{-\sqrt{\frac{s+k}{a}}x}
$$

and due to the boundary conditions $\phi_1(s) = 0,\phi_2(s) = c_0$ so

$$
C(s,x) = c_0e^{-\sqrt{\frac{s+k}{a}}x}
$$

and finally

$$
c(t,x) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[C(s,x)\right]=\frac{c_0 x e^{-\left(\frac{x^2}{4 a t}+k t\right)}}{2 \sqrt{a\pi }  t^{3/2}},\ \ \ \frac {x}{\sqrt{a}}\gt 0
$$

NOTE

The answer above considers the boundary conditions at $x = 0$ as initial conditions (Dirac impulses). To consider a step at $x = 0$ with amplitude $c_0$ then the boundary conditions should be $\phi_1(s) = \frac{c_0}{s}$ and then

$$
C(s,x) = \frac{c_0}{s}e^{-\sqrt{\frac{s+k}{a}}x}
$$

with inverse Laplace transform

$$
c(t,x) = \frac{1}{2} c_0 e^{x \left(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{a}}\right)} \left(2-\text{erfc}\left(\frac{2 t \sqrt{a k}-x}{2 \sqrt{a t}}\right)+e^{2 x \sqrt{\frac{k}{a}}}
   \text{erfc}\left(\frac{2 t \sqrt{a k}+x}{2 \sqrt{a t}}\right)\right)
$$

Follows a plot for $k=a=1, c_0=2,\ \ 0\le x\le 1, \ \ 0 \le t\le 2$.

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. How did you use the boundary condition could you explain please, And verify wheather my last step $(4)$ is correct or not?

Comment: Boundary condition for time version*

Comment: The $c(t,x)$ can be obtained from a transform table.

Comment: Thanks, the steps are understandable, could also please explain how did you use the boundary conditions?

Comment: Here is my understanding of you got the coefficient $\phi_1$‘s and $\phi_2$ ‘s values. Provided  x tends to $\infty$ . we have an $(\phi_1~e^{\infty}+ \phi_2~ e^{-\infty}) = \infty$ to avoid that we take $\phi_1 = 0$. So $ (0 +  \phi_2~ e^{-\infty})=0$. And $\phi_2 = C_0$

Comment: Yes. This is the reason behind the choice for $\phi_1, \phi_2$

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cesareo , but still slightly doubtful on $c(t,x)$. So for $c(0,x) = 0$  But in the inverse Laplace, putting t = 0 gives $\frac{....}{0} = $ undefined.

Comment: We can use the initial value theorem from Laplace which states. $c(0,x) = \lim_{s\to \infty}s C(s,x)$ giving $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cesaro. I appreciate a lot, I will go through every step again. Btw which topic should I specifically focus on to understand it better and are there any prerequisites besides PDE’s and ODE’s which would help me better understand. for example I have never heard of Dirac impulses, so need to learn about that. Though I understand the whole Laplace transformation you wrote.